# Custom client side validation attribute with parameter in ASP.NET Core using IClientModelValidator

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, validation, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm attempting to create my own client side validation attribute that would validate the property of a form on submit. I have been referencing the following Microsoft document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.1#custom-validation.

I am unsure on how to add the validation rule to jQuery's validator object. This is how far I have gotten:

My ValidationAttribute is as follows

```
public class CannotEqualValue : ValidationAttribute, IClientModelValidator
{
    private readonly string _value;

    public CannotEqualValue(string value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val", "true");
        MergeAttribute(
            context.Attributes, "data-val-cannotbevalue", GetErrorMessage()); //???
        MergeAttribute(
            context.Attributes, "data-val-cannotbevalue-value", _value);      //???
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(
        object value, 
        ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var category = (Category) validationContext.ObjectInstance;

        if (category.Name == _value)
            return new ValidationResult(GetErrorMessage());

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    private bool MergeAttribute(
        IDictionary<string, string> attributes, 
        string key, 
        string value)
    {
        if (attributes.ContainsKey(key)) return false;

        attributes.Add(key, value);
        return true;
    }

    private string GetErrorMessage()
    {
        return $"Name cannot be {_value}.";
    }
}
```

The ValidationAttribute is used in a model like so

```
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required and must not be empty.")]
    [StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Name must not exceed 200 characters.")]
    [CannotEqualValue("Red")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I am referencing both jQuery validation and unobtrusive in my page.

I am unsure on how to add the rule to jQuery's validator object:

```
$.validator.addMethod("cannotbevalue",
    function(value, element, parameters) {
        //???
    });

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("cannotbevalue",
    [],
    function(options) {
        //???
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `MergeAttribute(..)` lines of code in the `AddValidation()` method are correct and will add the `data-val-*` attributes for client side validation.

Your scripts need to be

```
$.validator.addMethod("cannotbevalue", function(value, element, params) {
    if ($(element).val() == params.targetvalue) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('cannotbevalue', ['value'], function(options) {
    options.rules['cannotbevalue'] = { targetvalue: options.params.value };
    options.messages['cannotbevalue'] = options.message;
});
```

Comment: The data-val attributes are added, however the validation still isn't firing: <input class="form-control frmInput" id="categoryName" placeholder="Name" type="text" data-val="true" data-val-cannotbevalue="Name cannot be Red." data-val-cannotbevalue-value="Red" data-val-length="Name should not exceed 200 characters." data-val-length-max="200" data-val-required="Name is required and must not be empty." name="Category.Name" value="">

Comment: And the scripts work just fine (I have tested it - if you enter "Red" and tab out a validation message will be displayed in your `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Category.Name)` placeholder (or the tag helper if your using that)

Comment: Hi Stephen. I inspected the element in Chrome developer tools to obtain that snippet so it is the html that was generated.

Comment: Why change the `id` attribute (although its irrelevant). Use you browser tools to debug the scripts. I assume you have included both `jquery.validate.js` and `juuery.validate.unobtrusive.js` and the scripts are in the correct order?

Comment: And here is a [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/k0nDmX) to prove it. Enter "Red" in the textbox and tab out - the validation message is displayed

Comment: Thanks for this fiddle; I'll use it to compare to mine to see if I'm missing anything.

Comment: Your script worked wonders thank you. However, for it to work I had to place it outside of $(document).ready...why is this?

Comment: Its the way jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` works when parsing the html to read the `data-val-*` attributes and add the rules to the `$.validator` (if you put it in `$(document).ready()` its too late and the rule is not added)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182782/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-trystan-wilcock).